# Build different number of vectors/maps during runtime, to insert into BST - C++

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, maps, binary-search-tree

The problem: So earlier the requirement for this C++ program was to just deal with one file's input (Each line represents the average of 10 minutes of the weather detail, about 50k lines). The end user wanted to be able to find out the average of the weather attributes for: a) A specified month and year, b)Average for each month of a specified year, c) Total for each month of a specified year, and d) average of each month of a specified year outputted to a .csv file.

Example: (First 4 lines of input csv)

```
WAST,DP,Dta,Dts,EV,QFE,QFF,QNH,RF,RH,S,SR,ST1,ST2,ST3,ST4,Sx,T
1/01/2010 9:00,8,151,23,0.1,1014.6,1018.1,1018.2,0,43.3,7,813,23.6,27,26.9,25.4,10,20.98
1/01/2010 9:10,8.7,161,28,0.1,1014.6,1018.1,1018.2,0,44.4,6,845,23.7,26.9,26.9,25.4,10,21.37
1/01/2010 9:20,8.9,176,21,0.2,1014.6,1018.1,1018.2,0,43.4,6,877,23.8,26.9,26.9,25.4,9,21.96
```

Solution: As not all the data from each line was required, upon reading in each line, they're parsed, segregated and built into an object instance of 'Weather', which consists of:

```
Date m_dateObj;
Time m_timeObj;
float m_windSpeed;
float m_solarRadiation;
float m_airTemperature;
```

A vector of Weather object was made to host this information.

Now, the problem has expanded to multiple files (150K-500K lines of data). Reading in multiple files is fine, all the data is retrieved and converted to Weather object with no problems, I'm just having trouble with the design(more specifically the syntax aspect of it, I know what I want to do). Additionally, there is a new option introduced where the user will enter dd/mm/yy and instances of highest solarRadiation for that day will be outputted(This requires me to have access to each specific object of weather and I cant just store aggregates).

BST and Maps are mandatory, so what I thought was: Data is read in line by line, for each line - Convert into Weather obj, store into a vector specifically for that month+year, so for every month of every year there will be a different vector eg; jan2007, feb2007, jan2008 etc. and each of these vectors are stored in a map:

```
map<pair<int, int>, vector<Weather> > monthMap;
```

So it looks like

```
<pair<3,2007>, march2007Vec>
```

and stores these maps into the BST (which I would need to randomize since its sorted data, to avoid making my BST a linked list, tips on how to do it? I found snippets for self-balancing trees that I might implement). This should work as the key for all maps are unique, thus making all BST nodes unique.

So it would look like this -

```
    User runs program
    Program opens files (there is a txt file with file names in it)
    For each file
        Open file
        For each line
            Convert into weather Object
            Check month+year, 
            if map for combination exists, 
                add to that vector (eg march2007)
            else
                create new vector store in new map 
        Close file
    add all maps to BST
    BST will self sort
    Provide user with menu to choose from
```

The actual computation of what the user needs is pretty simple, I just need help figuring out how to actually make it so there are n numbers of maps and vectors (n = number of maps = number of vectors, I think), as I don't know how many months/years there will be.

Heres a snippet of my code to get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Weather> monthVec;
    map<pair<int, int>, vector<Weather> > monthMap;
    map<pair<int, int>, vector<Weather> >::iterator itr;
    int count = 0;
    bool found = false;
    Weather weatherObj;
    ifstream weatherFileList;
    weatherFileList.open("data/met_index.txt");
    if(weatherFileList.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Success";
        while (!weatherFileList.eof())
        {
            string data;
            string fileName;
            getline(weatherFileList, fileName);
            cout << fileName << endl;
            fileName = "data/" + fileName;
            cout << fileName << endl;
            ifstream weatherFile;
            weatherFile.open(fileName.c_str());
            getline(weatherFile, data);
            while (!weatherFile.eof())
            {
                getline(weatherFile, data);
                if (!data.empty())
                {
                    weatherObj = ConvertData(data);
                    //cout << count << " " << weatherObj.GetTime().ToString() << endl;
                    //monthVec.push_back(weatherObj);
//                    for (itr = monthMap.begin(); itr != monthMap.end(); ++itr)
//                    {
//
//                    }
                    int month = weatherObj.GetDate().GetMonth();
                    int year = weatherObj.GetDate().GetYear();
                    itr = monthMap.find(make_pair(month,year));
                    if(itr != monthMap.end())
                    {
                        monthVec = itr->second;
                        monthVec.push_back(weatherObj);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    count++;
                }
                //cout << data << endl;
            }
            weatherFile.close();
        }
        listOptions();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not open";
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    cout << monthVec.size() << "/" << monthVec.capacity();
    return 0;
}
```

Apologies for the untidy code, so I was thinking about how to make it so for every new combination there's a new vector placed in a new map, but because of my inexperience, I don't know how to syntax it or even search it well.

TLDR: Need to map unknown number of combinations of ,VectorOfObject>

Would one make a switch case and have 12 vectors, one for each month hardcoded and just store all February (2007 2008 2009 etc) details in it, that would mean a lot of unnecessary processing.

How would one create different vectors without actually giving them a unique name for reference in the code, (<3,2007>,March2007)

How would one retrieve the contents of the vector(Of which we don't know the name, sure we know the key is 03 2007 aka march 2007, but wouldn't we need an explicit name to open the vector? march2007.find()), which is inside a map.

Thanks for the read, and potential help!

Please do Direct Message me if you'd like to see the problem in more detail, I would be grateful!

Comment: Just do `monthMap[{month,year}].push_back(weatherObj);` Map's `operator[]` implements "return existing value if present, construct a new value otherwise" logic.

Comment: Oh, that's really useful, thanks! However, I still don't understand what it would return, as monthVec is used for all (month,year) combinations, so wouldnt monthVec pretty much have all the data?

Comment: It would return a vector stored in the map at the key `{month,year}`. Remove `monthVec` - it's only confusing you.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I got the information being stored into the map, but I can't seem to retrieve it.            `for(itr = monthMap.begin(); itr != monthMap.end(); itr++)
            {
                cout << itr->first.first << "/" << itr->first.second << itr->second << endl;
            }`

Comment: Nvm, working now, thanks again! 

`for (map<pair<int, int>, vector<Weather> >::iterator it = monthMap.begin(); it != monthMap.end(); ++it) {
            //cout << it->first.first << "/" << it->first.second << endl;
            cout << "Size of " << it->first.first << "/" << it->first.second << " vector is : " << it->second.size() << endl;
            totalobjs+=it->second.size();
            totalmonths++;`